# What fonts can be used with pygame.font.SysFont()?

Tags: python, fonts, pygame

So far I've found that Calibri, Courier, and Times New Roman can be used with `pygame.font.SysFont()`. It takes the name of a font as a string as an argument. Would it be possible to put any font name, as long as its a string, as the font argument? Or is there a select number of fonts you can use?

Comment: Any installed font should work.  There is also `pygame.freetype.SysFont()` which will take a comma-separated string list of fonts to try.

Comment: While the font classes of the `freetype` module are generally better than the "old ones" in the `font` module, you can use a comma-separated list as font name for `pygame.font.SysFont`, too.

Answer (score 1):

Any font in the list returned from `pygame.font.get_fonts()` can be used.  This is a list of all the system fonts (ones built into the running system).  If you have your own .ttf file you want to use, you can instead use `pygame.font.Font`.  The advantage of that is you know the font you want is available (since you are bundling it with your game).  With system fonts, you don't necessarily know what fonts will be available on the user's system.